# C# time in microseconds

Tags: c#

I am searching how to format time including microseconds.
I'm using class DateTime, it allowes (using properties) to get data till miliseconds, which is not enougth.
I tried using Ticks, but I didn't know how to translate it to microseconds.

Comment: Be careful with DateTime.Now, it is not accurate to the microsecond. Try System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch to grab the time. Also make sure you have a high-resolution system clock.

Comment: Yes, You are right. It took my time to understand this comment. Although It presents the time in microsceonds, the time is not in microseconds.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You can use `"ffffff"` in a format string to represent microseconds:

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.ffffff"));
```

To convert a number of ticks to microseconds, just use:

```
long microseconds = ticks / (TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond / 1000);
```

If these don't help you, please provide more information about exactly what you're trying to do.

EDIT: I originally multiplied `ticks` by 1000 to avoid losing accuracy when dividing `TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond` by 1000. However, It turns out that the `TicksPerMillisecond` is actually a constant value of 10,000 - so you can divide by 1000 with no problem, and in fact we could just use:

```
const long TicksPerMicrosecond = 10;

...

long microseconds = ticks / TicksPerMicrosecond;
```

Comment: I used both of the opyions the problem is that I get the microseconds always zero. It seems like it can't get the resolution of that.

Comment: Then that's not a formatting problem, it's a resolution problem. Where are you getting the data from to start with? If you're trying to time how long something takes, you should use the `Stopwatch` class.

Comment: No. I just need it for the logger. For every event in the system I enter at the beginning the time it happened.
Any suggetsions ?

Comment: You could try fetching the accurate system time using P/Invoke, but I don't know how accurate you'll find it to be... and it may be a bit of a pain.

Comment: I tried it another windows (mine is vista) and it resolution f the micrseconds

Comment: I think better approach is to use `Stopwatch` class. When using date time ticks it offten returns 0 if function is really fast.

Comment: @EdgarsŠturms: Stopwatch is the right answer for measuring *elapsed* times - but it's not appropriate to obtain the "time of day".

Answer (score 21):

I was unable to get Johns tick to micorosecond conversion to work. Here is how I was able to measure Microsecond and Nanosecond resolution by using ticks and the Stopwatch:

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();

// Do something you want to time

sw.Stop();

long microseconds = sw.ElapsedTicks / (Stopwatch.Frequency / (1000L*1000L));
long nanoseconds = sw.ElapsedTicks / (Stopwatch.Frequency / (1000L*1000L*1000L));

Console.WriteLine("Operation completed in: " + microseconds + " (us)");
Console.WriteLine("Operation completed in: " + nanoseconds + " (ns)");
```

Comment: sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds is nice. Then divide by 1000 to get microseconds.

Comment: This is not quite right, because (Stopwatch.Frequency / (1000L*1000L))  being a long value leaves everything after a decimal for example if the result of the equation in the line above (of my comment) is 2.8576 which is technically 3 but sw.ElapsedTicks will be divided by 2 not 2.8 or 3, which is totally wrong.

Answer (score 11):

"ffffff" is what you need.

```
return DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.ffffff");
```

Comment: I used it the problem is that it always prints zero at the microseconds, like it doesn't calculate it.

Comment: This is not a problem with formatting, this is a problem with DateTime.Now accuracy. Try using System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.

Comment: I tried it another windows (mine is vista) and it resolution f the micrseconds

Answer (score 4):

It's:

```
return DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.ffffff");
```

for the whole time stamp in format hours:minutes:seconds:microseconds

```
return DateTime.Now.ToString(".ffffff");
```

if you need only residual microseconds.