# Advance a date_time by seconds + microseconds and display the result?

Tags: c#-3.0

I'm attempting to print a timestamp to string, where :

Each timestamp is based on 1970.1.1 and incremented by a (long)amount of seconds and a (long) amount of microseconds(always less then 1s total).

Here's what I'm doing :

```
DateTime TimeStamp = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);            
TimeSpan span = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, (int)Soc, (int)Fracsec.Fracsec);
TimeStamp += span;
```

I've just noticed that DateTime and TimeSpan use milliseconds instead of microseconds and it is imperative for me that I use microseconds, can anyone tell me how to achieve that?

What I'm trying to do next is to display the result in one operation (hopefully). Any way to do that as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Ticks` property to achieve microsecond fidelity and `DateTime.Format()` to display it.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206367/c-time-in-microseconds) for more details.  10 `Ticks` is equal to 1 microsecond.

There is also a [StopWatch class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) that provides for more accurate measurement of elapsed time.

Comment: Aren't ticks individually dependant on the machine itself?

Comment: @Maciek: No, not the ones in DateTime/TimeSpan.

Comment: I found a post on MSDN that goes into some details on this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/netfxbcl/thread/7146230d-e304-4636-86c5-d2e57588c33c

Answer (score 1):

DateTime is more accurate than just milliseconds - look at the [`DateTime.Ticks`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx) and [`TimeSpan.Ticks`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.ticks.aspx) properties. A tick represents 100 nanoseconds (i.e. there are 10 ticks per microsecond; 10,000 per millisecond.) This is defined in [`TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.tickspermillisecond.aspx) (a constant).

(One thing to be aware of is that this sort of tick is *not* the same as the tick in the [`Stopwatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class, which varies by timer.)