# Searching for smallest time value in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

By using C# built-in  API

```
System.DateTime.Now.Millisecond
```

I can generate milliseconds.

But When I think about

- [Microsecond](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond)
- [Nanosecond](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond)
- [Picosecond](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picosecond)
- [Femtosecond](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Femtosecond)
- [Attosecond](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attosecond)

I could not find any built-in functions from

```
System.DateTime
```

Could anyone give me suggestion please?

Comment: Divide the milliseconds by the necessary amount? Erm, make that multiply. You'll never get the proper precision though. E.g. microseconds will always be multiples of 1000. Useless really.

Comment: Wow. You must really want accurate timestamps in your log files :-)

Comment: `Ticks` will probably be the smallest amount of time you can get using native C# methods and even they will be less than reliable since your code doesn't run that quickly. Even ANSI C++ doesn't provide that granularity.

Comment: What is this ANSI C++ of which you speak? ISO took over the standards many moons ago and ANSI, like other national standards bodies, simply rubber-stamps the ISO documents nowadays :-)

Comment: Consider it a relic from the days that I actually felt like I was coding something rather than just reusing something someone at Microsoft coded for me. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Given that the [resolution of the date/time is only ten milliseconds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx), it's probably considered unnecessary to try and have properties containing anything with a smaller resolution than one millisecond.

The values for them would simply be the milliseconds value with some zeros tacked on the end.

Computers have come a long way since mid last century but, given that a photon running at the speed limit of the universe<sup>(a)</sup> will only cross a few hydrogen atoms in one attosecond, it's a stretch trying to imagine how useful such a resolution would be.

A (classic) CPU running at 5GHz would only get through five *billionths* of an instruction in that timeframe.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> One of my favorite quotes: The speed of light. It's not just a good idea, it's the *law.*

Answer (score 1):

For high resolution timing, you could look into the [QueryPerformanceCounter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. I think it's also exposed via the `Stopwatch` class in C#. Of course, this is only a timer, not a walltime, so you'll have to combine it with `DateTime` to get actual timestamps.

[SO1416139](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416139/how-to-get-timestamp-of-tick-precision-in-net-c) has details on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The smallest time unit on the Windows platform is the millisecond. You are not going to get any more accurate than that.

Answer (score 0):

The smallest unit of time is the [tick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.ticks%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), which is equal to 100 nanoseconds. A tick can be negative or positive.

Comment: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.ticks%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) Is the link for a actual example.  My programming knowledge isn't developed enough to just spout of code.

Answer (score 0):

The most accurate you can get are ticks, which are 100 nano second amounts (0.1 Microseconds). You can access this via the Ticks property of a DateTime field, which is the number of ticks since 1 Jan 0001

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct methods available to get this..need to write our own method to get this...see this url 
1) http://www.dotnetperls.com/convert-nanoseconds 
2) [C# time in microseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206367/c-sharp-time-in-microseconds)

Thanks,
Snoby